# Keep background image aligned at top of div at all times while avoiding text overlap

Tags: html, css

I have a 2 column layout which is meant to have text on the right and an image on the left. The image has to be responsive, though, and the whole image may or may not need to be visible. Since there is no guarantee as to how each image will look, I set the left column to have a background image. Problem is, though, that the image doesn't stay top-aligned at all times.

I tried setting `vertical-align: top` to the left column div but that didn't make a difference. I'd give the background image a fixed width/height but the results may not always be what is expected in that the background image may be cut off too much in smaller screens.

I'd use just an image in the left column but since it's meant to be left aligned and "cropped" by it's parent container, that could cause alignment issues as well. Also, in mobile, the left column is moved above the right one and more of the image can be seen.

Here's a fiddle :

```css
.product-txt-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 52%;
  min-height: 516px;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 88px;
  padding-bottom: 90px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .product-txt-right {
    min-height: 381px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-bottom: 49px;
    margin-left: -27px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .product-txt-right {
    min-height: 383px;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: -27px;
    padding-bottom: 49px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .product-single-description div:nth-child(2) {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.product-single-description {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: -66px;
  padding-top: 66px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .product-single-description {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .product-single-description {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  .product-single-description {
    display: block;
  }
}

.product-detail-gallery {
  min-height: 516px;
  max-height: 800px;
  width: 48%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 147%;
  background-position: top right;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .product-detail-gallery {
    min-height: 383px;
    background-size: 140%;
    background-position: 115% 54%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .product-detail-gallery {
    min-height: 383px;
    width: 85%;
    background-size: 151%;
    background-position: 107% 63%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  .product-detail-gallery {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 286px;
    background-size: 93%;
    background-position: -381% 79%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .product-detail-gallery {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 286px;
    background-size: 104%;
    background-position: 571% 80%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .product-detail-gallery {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 286px;
    background-size: 119%;
    background-position: 130% 82%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="product-single-description">

  <div class="product-detail-gallery" style="background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/prvG5f85/wowza-gball-main.png)">
  </div>
  <div class="product-txt-right">

    <h2>Mauris neque nisi</h2>
    <p>Fermentum a congue vel, semper eget libero. Donec aliquam, velit sed imperdiet pretium, urna elit lobortis erat, id feugiat velit arcu id purus. Sed a accumsan tortor. Ut turpis magna, sagittis sed libero at, hendrerit semper urna. Vivamus venenatis eget diam ac varius. Mauris id consectetur mi. Cras sapien neque, placerat et mauris eu, iaculis consectetur mi. Phasellus eu eros lacinia, rutrum ex in, dignissim lacus. Suspendisse enim ex, imperdiet ut scelerisque nec, laoreet ut libero</p>
    <p>Fermentum a congue vel, semper eget libero. Donec aliquam, velit sed imperdiet pretium, urna elit lobortis erat, id feugiat velit arcu id purus. Sed a accumsan tortor. Ut turpis magna, sagittis sed libero at, hendrerit semper urna. Vivamus venenatis eget diam ac varius. Mauris id consectetur mi. Cras sapien neque, placerat et mauris eu, iaculis consectetur mi. Phasellus eu eros lacinia, rutrum ex in, dignissim lacus. Suspendisse enim ex, imperdiet ut scelerisque nec, laoreet ut libero</p>
    <p>Fermentum a congue vel, semper eget libero. Donec aliquam, velit sed imperdiet pretium, urna elit lobortis erat, id feugiat velit arcu id purus. Sed a accumsan tortor. Ut turpis magna, sagittis sed libero at, hendrerit semper urna. Vivamus venenatis eget diam ac varius. Mauris id consectetur mi. Cras sapien neque, placerat et mauris eu, iaculis consectetur mi. Phasellus eu eros lacinia, rutrum ex in, dignissim lacus. Suspendisse enim ex, imperdiet ut scelerisque nec, laoreet ut libero</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ideally, if the image could stay a background image and somehow be responsive while being aligned at the top of the left column, that would be perfect. However, if this is not possible and some other method is needed, then that could still work.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code has a number of media queries that adjust the `background-position`. If you want it to always be top-aligned and it doesn't need to look the same at all widths, why not set it to always be positioned at the top?

If you want the whole image to display regardless of the width, you can set the background width to 100% and include a minimum height for the section.